# Sending data to a independent remote server

Tags: node.js, express

I want to send a json object to another server, independent of my website.

The API I am using requires a user (user x in this case) to log into their service to be authorized so user x can manipulate user x's list. However, other users can't write to x's list. So, users need to request an item to be added to x's list, then a server who is logged into x's account can add it to x's list. Refer to the image below.

http://imgur.com/a/wT53t

I am using node/express.js for the servers on the user's side. However, I don't know what I should use for a server who's only job is to receive requests and write to x's list. Can you provide some guidance as to how I can achieve something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options here:

- You have to refresh the list in the realtime for connected users.
  To achieve this you should use either: [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)(e.g. [socket.io](http://socket.io/)) or [LongPolling](https://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery).
- In second option you dont have to refresh the list in the realtime. You simply use express. Accept data and refresh the list server-side.

**Auth** with web sockets:

Once understanding the nature of web sockets, you're free to build any logic around them, including authentication/authorization. The great library doing lots of auth things is [passport.js](http://passportjs.org/).

Very quick and abstract example of server-side:

```
socket.on('auth', function(data) {
  const vendor = data.vendor,
      token = data.id

  switch(vendor) {
    /* 
      Here you grab through some social API user social id 
      and save it to database
    */
  }

  /* set socket as logged in */
  socket.logged = true 

  /* or even save user object */
  socket.user = { vendor, token }
})
```

Next time you need authorized user, you check:

```
socket.on('mustBeAuthorized', function() {
  if(socket.logged || socket.user) {
     /* Continue your logic*/
  }
})
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. Do websockets also provide a place for my independent authorized server?

Comment: About "independent server" again, you're free to build any logic you wish. Web sockets are very flexible.